# Locked myself out of S3 bucket through incorrect bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to apply policy to deny access when non secure transport

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "denyInsecureTransport",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

But the problem is I set the wrong condition, it must be **false** instead of **true**. Now I can't control this bucker (can't edit the policy, delete bucket ..).
I am having Administrator access.

[image: Error on access S3]

How can I fix that? Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've effectively denied all IAM-entities access to the bucket unless they use insecure transport (HTTP).

You can perform the API calls to fix this over HTTP (not a good strategy) or Log in with your root account user and change the policy as the Root Account User is not affected by IAM policies.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete bucket policy it this way

passing the --endpoint-url parameter with the http endpoint of your bucket's region in the command example below

aws s3api delete-bucket-policy --bucket my-bucket --endpoint-url http://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/