# Bad policy on my bucket in S3 and now I don't have any access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I have applied a bad policy in my bucket and now I can't access to any configuration.

This is the policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "instance-ip"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Any solution? Please :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locked myself out of S3 bucket through incorrect bucket policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392547/locked-myself-out-of-s3-bucket-through-incorrect-bucket-policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login as root account and then delete the policy.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access

Answer (score 0):

Login as your root account (not IAM) and you will be able to remove the policy. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access